# c# SHA256 ToBase64String of string not the same as test case

Tags: c#, json, sha256, tobase64string, cybersource

I'm working on a body payload digest for a post request.

I'm using the test case provided to try and get the same output base64 as CyberSource does using their test values and test method.

```
public static string GenerateDigest() {
     var digest = "";
     var bodyText = "{ your JSON payload }";
     using (var sha256hash = SHA256.Create()) {
         byte[] payloadBytes = sha256hash
             .ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyText));
         digest = Convert.ToBase64String(payloadBytes);
         digest = "SHA-256=" + digest;
     }
     return digest;
}
```

[image: Digest]
The test case has the following JSON payload:

```
{
  "clientReferenceInformation": {
    "code": "TC50171_3"
  },
  "processingInformation": {
    "commerceIndicator": "internet"
  },
  "paymentInformation": {
    "card": {
      "number": "4111111111111111",
      "expirationMonth": "12",
      "expirationYear": "2031",
      "securityCode": "123"
    }
  },
  "orderInformation": {
    "amountDetails": {
      "totalAmount": "102.21",
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "billTo": {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "company": "Visa",
      "address1": "1 Market St",
      "address2": "Address 2",
      "locality": "san francisco",
      "administrativeArea": "CA",
      "postalCode": "94105",
      "country": "US",
      "email": "test@cybs.com",
      "phoneNumber": "4158880000"
    }
  }
}
```

[image: CyberSource image]

The test payload I've attempted to generate the base64 string with are the following:

```
var bodyText = @"
{
  ""clientReferenceInformation"": {
    ""code"": ""TC50171_3""
  },
  ""processingInformation"": {
    ""commerceIndicator"": ""internet""
  },
  ""paymentInformation"": {
    ""card"": {
      ""number"": ""4111111111111111"",
      ""expirationMonth"": ""12"",
      ""expirationYear"": ""2031"",
      ""securityCode"": ""123""
    }
  },
  ""orderInformation"": {
    ""amountDetails"": {
      ""totalAmount"": ""102.21"",
      ""currency"": ""USD""
    },
    ""billTo"": {
      ""firstName"": ""John"",
      ""lastName"": ""Doe"",
      ""company"": ""Visa"",
      ""address1"": ""1 Market St"",
      ""address2"": ""Address 2"",
      ""locality"": ""san francisco"",
      ""administrativeArea"": ""CA"",
      ""postalCode"": ""94105"",
      ""country"": ""US"",
      ""email"": ""test@cybs.com"",
      ""phoneNumber"": ""4158880000""
    }
  }
}
";
```

and..

```
var bodyjson = new
            {
                clientReferenceInformation = 
                new { code = "TC50171_3" },
                processingInformation =
                new {
                commerceIndicator = "internet"},
                paymentInformation =
                new { card =
                    new {
                        number = "4111111111111111",
                        expirationMonth = "12",
                        expirationYear = "2031",
                        securityCode = "123"
                    }
                },
                orderInformation = new
                {
                    amountDetails = new
                    {
                        totalAmount = "102.21",
                        currency = "USD"
                    },
                    billTo = new
                    {
                        firstName = "John",
                        lastName = "Doe",
                        company = "Visa",
                        address1 = "1 Market St",
                        address2 = "Address 2",
                        locality = "san francisco",
                        administrativeArea = "CA",
                        postalCode = "94105",
                        country = "US",
                        email = "test@cybs.com",
                        phoneNumber = "4158880000"
                    }
                }
            };
            var bodystring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyjson, Formatting.Indented);
```

The Sha256 byte64 returned should be:

`SHA-256=a/goIo1XUCr80rnKFCWp7yRpwVL50E9RaunuEHh11XM=`

[image]

The the test case code above is all from the Cybersource getting started guide. But my body string just does not produce the same result.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the correct hash with `bodyText`?

Comment: Compare the 2 texts byte by byte, i assure you they will be different. That is your mission if you choose to accept it

Comment: @TheGeneral this is the way. I found two lines missing in the json payload and I was really excited. But then tested again and still nothing.

I've update the question with more structure. It surely can not be this hard, it's 3 lines of code and a Json payload - It must be something ridiculous.

Comment: The payload used in [CyberSource sample code](https://github.com/CyberSource/cybersource-rest-samples-csharp/blob/master/Source/Samples/Authentication/StandAloneHttpSignature.cs#L38-L71) is indented using only 1 space (vs 2 in your example), uses unix-style line endings and has no leading or trailing whitespace

Answer (score 0):

```
string body = "{\n" +
                "  \"clientReferenceInformation\": {\n" +
                "    \"code\": \"TC50171_3\"\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  \"processingInformation\": {\n" +
                "    \"commerceIndicator\": \"internet\"\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  \"orderInformation\": {\n" +
                "    \"billTo\": {\n" +
                "      \"firstName\": \"john\",\n" +
                "      \"lastName\": \"doe\",\n" +
                "      \"address1\": \"201 S. Division St.\",\n" +
                "      \"postalCode\": \"48104-2201\",\n" +
                "      \"locality\": \"Ann Arbor\",\n" +
                "      \"administrativeArea\": \"MI\",\n" +
                "      \"country\": \"US\",\n" +
                "      \"phoneNumber\": \"999999999\",\n" +
                "      \"email\": \"test@cybs.com\"\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    \"amountDetails\": {\n" +
                "      \"totalAmount\": \"10\",\n" +
                "      \"currency\": \"USD\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  \"paymentInformation\": {\n" +
                "    \"card\": {\n" +
                "      \"expirationYear\": \"2031\",\n" +
                "      \"number\": \"5555555555554444\",\n" +
                "      \"securityCode\": \"123\",\n" +
                "      \"expirationMonth\": \"12\",\n" +
                "      \"type\": \"002\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";
```